# Is Team foundation server a replacement for visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

If I buy TFS will it covers the visual studio 2012 functionalities such as creating projects, build , compile. Or TFS it is mainly a support service to VS to give VS more collaboration and management control? Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS (Team Foundation Server) is a tool for the Application Lyfecycle Management (ALM) process.

It delivers the features such as:

- Version Control
- Requirements Management
- Build Automation
- Test Case Management

It enables full integration with Visual Studio IDE and gives the collaboration and management features in use for a team's ALM process.

So basically, Visual Studio is the development platform while TFS is the enhancer and collaborator for multiple instaces of Developers, Testers, Analyzers and vice versa.

TFS don't have the abilities like: development, creating projects.